# Task not run by crontab

Tags: debian, shell-script, cron

`crontab` strangely does not execute my script, although the script is running just fine from the shell terminal. I already made sure that scripts are separated from each other by a new line space. However, I am suspicious about the contents of my script. `crontab` executes `run.sh` which would later run `main.sh`.

This is the `/etc/crontab`:

```
* * */3 * *        root  source /opt/db_maintain/run.sh
```

This is the contents of `run.sh` which would call `main.sh` from inside:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#********* Saman *********
TM=$(date --date='40 days ago' '+%F %T')
TARGET=/opt/db_maintain/main.sh
TIMESTAMP=$(echo ${TM} | tr --delete ': -')
export TIMESTAMP
source $TARGET "$TM"
```

This is the beginning of `main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
##!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# main program entry point
#

source /opt/db_maintain/functions.sh
source /opt/db_maintain/constants.sh
source /opt/db_maintain/settings.sh
source /root/PASSWD_PGRS.sh

#read -s -t 0 -n 9999
#read -s -p "Enter password for ${USERNAME}: " PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this syntax in the cronjob:

```
* * */3 * *        root  /bin/bash /opt/db_maintain/run.sh
```

You used `source`. That is a [shell builtin command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) from `bash`. Therefore it can only be executed inside a `bash` shell or via a `bash` shell. The crontab just executes binaries, not shell commands. So you have to call a binary (`/bin/bash`), preferably by its abolute path.